# Simple JQuery script animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i created a simple html page :

index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="menu">      
        hello
    </div>  
     <div class="test">        
       Menu
     </div> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the app.js file:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.test').click(function(){
        $('body').animate({
            left: '500px'
            },200);
    })
}
$(document).ready(main)
```

I'm trying to understand what i did wrong , it seems like it should work..

was also tried to download `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` and to work with it , but still while clicking on the menu , the text is not moving ..

Comment: It is irrelevant to your problem, but it is good practice to keep `.js` files inside `<head>` tag and not `<body>`.

Comment: With your code at the bottom, you don't need to use `.ready()` at all. Just invoke the `main` function or remove the code from it.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that's not true at all, theres nothing wrong with putting js files at the bottom, it just means you dont have to call `.ready` because those files don't load until after the HTML has

Comment: @USer22999299 are you trying to animate both lines of text to the right?

Comment: i am trying to animate something.. for now , both of them.

Comment: @jmore009, I did not say it is wrong, I said it is good practice :)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: It's a good practice to have it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I add them at the top but it's personal preference, not good practice. Scripts at the top could potentially block the rendering of the page

Comment: @squint, I refered to [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `position` css property to `body` in order to work `left`.

```
body{
  position:relative;
}
```

REF : **http://api.jquery.com/animate/**

Comment: hm... to be able to animate i must set a css for this specific part ?

Comment: Works when I test it.

Comment: could you explain why i should set the css to the body in order to animate it? and why to set position to relative?

Comment: @USer22999299 Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible effect on elements if their  position style property is static, which it is by default. (from : http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: you have to set it to the body because thats what your code was targeting. And left, top, bottom and right properties do not apply to elements without absolute, relative, or fixed positioning

Comment: @USer22999299: [mdn CSS `left` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)